# How to import multiple objects in different files easily

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

```
application
├── folder
│       └── A.py --> class A:...
│       └── B.py --> class B:...  
│       └── C.py --> class C:...
└── __init.py__
```

What is the best way to get classes A, B and C into __init__.py?
Below is one way to do it

```
from .folder.A import A
from .folder.B import B
from .folder.C import C
```

But is there a simpler one liner I could be using? something like `from .folder.* import A,B,C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote would do it and there's no multi-module import one-liner unless you want to write a loop:

```py
import importlib
for sub in "A B C".split():
    globals()[sub] = getattr(importlib.import_module(".folder." + sub), sub)
```

I only wrote the above to show how unsightly this is.

Slightly better method is to do it in `folder.__init__`

```py
# folder.__init__
from A import *
from B import *
from C import *

# __init__
from .folder import *
```

To retain some control of this and prevent surprises, define `__all__` in individual modules to limit what's being pulled to the top:

```py
# folder.A
__all__ = ["A"]

# folder.B
__all__ = ["B"]

# etc.
```

Now, what I'd really recommend here is this: don't break things up into modules until you find a reason for it. If there's such a tight dependency between A/B/C that they always end up imported together -- which will be the case for your question -- put them all into a `folder.py` *module* (not even separate directory) and just do `from .folder import A, B, C` in the `__init__`. The reason for modules to exist is to loosen dependencies between code blocks and allow some of the code to be used without importing more. If some code must always be together, keep it in the same module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It's interesting that you mentioned not to break it up into modules. I initially had it all in one module just as you mentioned but thought it might be cleaner to have each class in separate files just because each class may get long and it might be unsightly to have one super long file. Interested to know your thoughts.

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference but with Python there's no obligation to maintain class-per-module structure. You also need to be aware that doing `from application.folder.A import A` will in fact import _everything_ because it first imports `application`, which would cascade the imports you asked about.